# emacs: non-contiguous buffer region

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want Emacs' syntax motion functions to ignore certain regions of the buffer; i.e. to correctly parse non-contiguous regions.  This can be done effectively if you can define the region to ignore as a comment and set parse-sexp-ignore-comments variable to true.

Here's the problem.  The primary mode has comments starting with '!' and ending with newline ('\n') and the buffer region I want ignored as a comment starts with "%{" and ends with "}%".  However, I cannot see any way to define these both as comments.  The mechanism to cope with multi-character comment delimiters in the syntax table is too specific to C to use here.  Does anyone have any other suggestions, text-properties, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can modify the syntax table similarly to what C does.  You can read up on syntax tables [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table).  Basically, you'll need to define `%` as punctuation and as a comment character, same with the `{` and `}`.

The description for the `/` character in C is:

```
        character: / (47, #o57, #x2f)
preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
       code point: 0x2F
           syntax: . 124b   which means: punctuation,
      is the first character of a comment-start sequence,
      is the second character of a comment-start sequence,
      is the second character of a comment-end sequence (comment style b)
```

Note: to get the description of a character, type `M-x describe-char` and it'll tell you all about the char after the point.

Similarly, the `*` character has the description (in C):

```
        character: * (42, #o52, #x2a)
preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
       code point: 0x2A
           syntax: . 23 which means: punctuation,
      is the second character of a comment-start sequence,
      is the first character of a comment-end sequence
```

Basically, you need to set up the comment-start and comment-end sequences, as described in [this part of the info pages](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Flags.html#Syntax-Flags).

I think you'd want to modify the syntax entries something like this:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?% ".14")
(modify-syntax-entry ?{ "(}2")
(modify-syntax-entry ?} "){3")
```

Though, I think keeping the `{` and `}` as a matched pair of parenthesis might confuse things...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, I already tried this before I came here to ask the question.  I found that the mechanism is too specific to C; the 'b' type of comment has to start with the first symbol of the 'a' type of comment, in this case '!' and '%' respectively.  In C, these are conveniently both '/'